# Conectar Query Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Buenas Tardes,
lo que me pasa es que tengo un query en sql server y cuando dejo de trabajar en el query por un tiempo se desconecta y al volver a conectar no me deja ejecutar el código que tengo, alguien sabe como puedo volver a conectarlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tal vez te sirva configurar el tiempo de espera de consulta remota, para que te dure más tiempo conectado, si bien no responde directamente a tu pregunta es un workaround posible

[image: Configuración de Propiedades del Servidor]